# CSRF token mismatch for every post request Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-9

I am getting Csrf token mismatch error on **every post request** I am making in the project. I am using ajax at some places and normal form submission at other places. However the error is constant.

I have tried several things as suggested on this site like

1. Setting `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false`.
2. Adding `@csrf` inside `<form></form>`
3. Adding `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />` and
   `$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');}});` before ajax call.
4. Running `php artisan  config:clear` `php artisan  route:clear` `composer dump-autoload`.
5. Running project on different browsers.

The error is same throughout. The application was working absolutely fine.
What is the thing I am missing?

Comment: Do you have any middleware which will interfere and change the token? or you can inspect the browser to check if CSRF token is generated properly. Also, Perform `php artisan key:generate` if you don't have the key. Also, You don't have to change `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE` value.

Comment: @MonishKhatri yes when i inspect i can see the token successfully, also I am facing same issues for post requests with and without any middleware.

Comment: can you share `'same_site'` parameter from your **config/session.php**.

Comment: Yes @a_man it is set to `'same_site' => null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **config/session.php** file, try setting `same_site` to `lax`,`null`.

After that run `php artisan config:cache`.